# Creating a SQL Function that inputs a parameter and returns a vendor with the lowest cost

Tags: sql, function, min

Here is the question:

Code    and execute the statement   to  create  a   function    called  PreferredVendor that    accepts a
product id  parameter   as  an  input   and returns the Vendor  ID  of  the Vendor  with    the lowest  cost
in  VendorProduct

I am having trouble returning the VendorID with the lowest Cost, here is the table structure

```
Create table VendorProduct(

VendorProductID int identity primary key,
Cost decimal(12,4),
ProductID int identity foreign key references Product(ProductID),
VendorID int identity foreign key references Vendor(VendorID)
)
```

The code I have created so far is the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PreferredVendor (@ProductID int)
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LowestVendorPrice int
    SELECT @LowestVendorPrice = VendorID FROM VendorProduct 
    WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
    RETURN @LowestVendorPrice
END
GO
```

I have not been able to find out how to use MIN here!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 2):

Use this select in your function

```
SELECT TOP 1 @LowestVendorPrice = VendorID FROM VendorProduct 
    WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
    ORDER BY Cost
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was completely overthinking the entire statement!